# What is the difference between draw and draw_networkx in Networkx library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, data-visualization, networkx

I was using regular `draw` function for my graphs and while reading someone's code I saw he used `draw_networkx` and looks like they are taking different parameters and default values.

I was wondering if anyone could explain me what they are more specifically used for.

Answer (score 1):

[Networkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/drawing.html) give you the answer (bold text is mine):

> [`draw()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw):
>   draw the graph as a **simple representation with no node labels or edge
>   labels and using the full Matplotlib figure area and no axis labels by
>   default**. See draw_networkx() for more full-featured drawing that
>   allows title, axis labels etc.
>
> [`draw_networkx()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx):
>   draw the graph with Matplotlib **with options for node positions,
>   labeling, titles, and many other drawing features**. See draw() for
>   simple drawing without labels or axes.

Comment: hi sentence, thanks for the answer. I guess I messed up my question, what I meant was why there is two of the same function. That's not we see in common. So why would one consider using draw() where there is no label etc, where he can just pass draw_networkx with the default parameter values. Thanks. (It was more of a question for people who been dealing with it to understand the logic!)

Comment: Your question is going to turn towards developers' intentions. I would say that it is a common practice to write down a basic function and then, during the evolution of the project, to develop richer functions.